# How does "\\d" work in java?

Tags: java, regex

example: `if(str.matches(".*\\d.*"))`

I used it recently to check if a value of an array contained a number.

What's the logic behind it? Why is the `.* .*` there? What does `\\d` mean?

EDIT: thank you all! such fast responses :)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the javadocs for the method you are using?  HINT!

Comment: Ah I tried searching for it but the pattern javadocs did not come up for some reason. I wanted to ask here to make sure I could get the most intuitive answer. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 7):

- `.` symbol matches any character except newline.
- `*` repeats the character behind it 0 or more times.
- `\d` matches any digit. The extra `\` in `\\d` is used to escape the backslash from the string.

So `.\\d.` matches any single character, a digit, and any single character. It will match the following: `a1b`, `p3k`, `&2@`

`.*\\d.*` matches 0 or more characters, a digit, and 0 or more characters. It will match the following: `2`, `11`, `123`, `asdf6klj`

If you want to match 1 or more characters you can use `+`, `{2,}`, `{3,5}`, etc.

`+` means repeat previous character 1 or more times.

`{2, }` means repeat previous character two or more times.

`{3, 5}` means repeat previous character 3 to 5 times.

For more details you can review many regex tutorials such as here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1):

`.*` means any squence of character. it matches zero eo more character .

`\\d` means a digit

So you match all strings that contains one digit. For more information see the documentation of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Comment: Please be precise. `.*` matches any *sequence* of *characters*, zero or more. (Not a *sign* - '+' or '-'.) And: contain *at least* one digit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression.

- `.` means any character
- `*` means any number (including 0!) of [the matcher before it]
- `\\d` is a digit

So, id you put it all together, this regex matches a string that has the following: Any number of any character, then a digit, and then any number of any character. If we translate this "formal" description to a more human readable one, it just means a string that has a digit somewhere in it.

Answer (score 0):

\d means if there is any digit but '\' is an escape sequence hence `'\\'` is used.

In C#, you can also use `@".*\d.*"`
(Not sure in Java but I feel it should work)

`*` denotes any number of characters.